# Is there any standard function to search for identical substrings within a string?

Tags: c#, string, function, substring

If I am having a `string` say for an example `"ABEFAB"`, it would take a length parameter `(eg. 2)` and then return a result which would show that there `ARE identical substrings` of that length in my `string`.

Comment: No, there's no such function in the standard C# library; however you can easily implment it via suffix array or (slightly more efficient but more complictated) suffix tree.

Comment: Seems like there ought to be a Regex answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
public static bool HasIdenticalSubStrings(string str, int len)
{
    bool returnValue = false;

    List<String> lst = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length - len; i++)
        lst.Add(str.Substring(i, len));

    returnValue = (lst.Distinct().Count() != lst.Count);

    return returnValue;
}
```

and call like

```
HasIdenticalSubStrings("ABEFAB", 2); //return true

HasIdenticalSubStrings("ABCDEF", 2); //return false
```

**Note:** You need to put some checks like `String.IsNullOrEmpty` check

**Efficient Method:**

```
public static bool HasIdenticalSubStrings(string str, int len)
{
    bool returnValue = false;

    List<String> lst = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length - len; i++)
    {
        String tempstr = str.Substring(i, len);
        if (lst.Contains(tempstr))
        {
            returnValue = true;
            break;
        }
        else
            lst.Add(tempstr);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Counter example: `HasIdenticalSubStrings("AAA", 2)` returns `false`, however `Substring(0, 2) == Substring(1, 2)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko:`HasIdenticalSubStrings("AAA", 1)` will return true but `HasIdenticalSubStrings("AAA", 2)` will always return false as there are no identical strings of length 2.

Comment: lst.Distinct().Count() is inefficient: the method's collecting all the substrings and compute count when only first collision detection is required

Comment: If substrings are not permitted to overlap (as in "AAA") the counter example is `HasIdenticalSubStrings("ABxAB", 2)` which returns `false` when `true` is expected

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* (however not that *efficient*) solution is

```
public static Boolean HasIdenticalSubStrings(String value, int length) 
{
  if (length <= 0)
    return false;
  else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return false;
  else if (value.Length <= length)
    return false;

  // HashSet is more efficient than List for Contains() operation
  HashSet<String> subStrings = new HashSet<String>();

  for (int i = 0; i <= value.Length - length; ++i) {
    String s = value.Substring(i, length);

    if (subStrings.Contains(s))
      return true;
    else
      subStrings.Add(s);
  }

  return false;
}
```

Test cases:

```
  HasIdenticalSubStrings("AAA", 2);    // true, overlaping "AA" substrings
  HasIdenticalSubStrings("ABxyAB", 2); // true
  HasIdenticalSubStrings("ABxAB", 2);  // true
  HasIdenticalSubStrings("ABCDEF", 2); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Contains` surves this puprose quite well. It doesn't take any length parameters, though, but I discovered that for my program it's not even necessary because there is a determined block size which I use.

Comment: Technically, you can check all the substrings of length 2 with a help of Substring/Contains; but it's not efficient unless the input string ("ABEFAB" in the question) is short enough. The standard solution is suffix array/tree

Comment: @DonBoitnott as I said I'm actually passing consequitive blocks of text of a specified length, not the length itself. So it works